# Android java trouble parsing JSON

Tags: java, android, json

I've parsed some simple json in the past but this one is giving me a bit more trouble. I'm trying to get data from Wikipedia's "on this day in history"

[Example URL with JSON output](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=September_17&rvprop=content&prop=revisions)

[Actual URL in regular HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_17)

Now if you pop the JSON URL into:
http://jsonlint.com/ to get a breakdown the first bit of trouble I have is after the object after pages in this case "27993" will always be different so how am I to fetch this if I don't know the name?

For testing purposes I have this code so far:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);  
input.close();  
JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(json.getString("query").toString()); 
JSONObject json3 = new JSONObject(json2.getString("pages").toString()); 
JSONObject json4 = new JSONObject(json3.getString("27993").toString()); 
JSONArray contacts = json4.getJSONArray("revisions");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(contacts.getString(0));    
return builder.toString();
```

That returns everything in the revisions array which leads me to my next question...is there an easy method to parse that output?

**EDIT: Revised code that solves issue #1 Now about parsing that output?**

```
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);  
            input.close();  
            JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(json.getString("query").toString()); 
            JSONObject json3 = new JSONObject(json2.getString("pages").toString()); 
            Iterator i = json3.keys();
            JSONObject j = null;
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    String key = i.next().toString();
                    j = json3.getJSONObject(key);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            JSONArray contacts = j.getJSONArray("revisions");
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(contacts.getString(0));    
            return builder.toString();
```

**The 2nd part of the question is there a simple solution to parsing such output. Here is a snip:**

> ":"{{pp-move-indef}}{{September
>   calendar|float=right}}\n{{ThisDateInRecentYears}}\n{{Day}}\n\n==Events==\n*
>   [[456]] – [[Remistus]], Roman general (''[[magister
>   militum]]''), is [[Siege|besiege]]d with a [[Goths|Gothic]] force at
>   [[Ravenna]] and later executed in the Palace ''in Classis'', outside
>   the city. \n*[[1111]] – Highest Galician nobility led by [[Pedro
>   Fr\u00f3ilaz de Traba]] and the bishop [[Diego Gelm\u00edrez]] crown
>   [[Alfonso VII of Le\u00f3n and Castile|Alfonso VII]] as \"[[kingdom of
>   Galicia|King of Galicia]]\".\n*[[1176]] – The [[Battle of
>   Myriokephalon]] is fought.\n*[[1462]] – The [[Battle of
>   \u015awiecino]] (also known as the Battle of \u017barnowiec) is fought
>   during [[Thirteen Years' War (1454\u201366)|Thirteen Years'
>   War]].\n*[[1577]] – The [[Peace of Bergerac]] is signed between
>   [[Henry III of France]] and the [[Huguenots]].\n*[[1630]] – The
>   city of [[Boston]]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()

Comment: i don't get your second question ?

Comment: Parsing the output. I was just wondering if there is a simple solution to it because this is what it returns: ":"{{pp-move-indef}}{{September calendar|float=right}}\n{{ThisDateInRecentYears}}\n{{Day}}\n\n==Events==\n* [[456]] &ndash; [[Remistus]], Roman general (''[[magister militum]]''), is [[Siege|besiege]]d with a [[Goths|Gothic]] force at [[Ravenna]] and later executed in the Palace ''in Classis'', outside the city. \n*[[1111]] &ndash;  etc etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject pages = new JSONObject(json.getJSONObject("pages"));

// Use this to get IDs
Iterator<String> keys = pages.keys();

// Then iterate
while (keys.hasNext()) {
  JSONObject page = new JSONObject(pages.get(keys.next()));
  // Do something with the page
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually did my own code from the link that guy posted before you posted this but this works too! Any ideas on parsing the output?